# Use 2nd Generation iPad (iOS 9.3.5) as touchscreen for late 2020 MacBook Air (Big Sur)

Tags: ipad, jailbreak

I teach online lessons and often use a digital whiteboard (Google Jamboard) to help teach. However, it can be difficult to write properly with a trackpad and so I tried using my old 2011 iPad. Unfortunately Google Jamboard (and seemingly all other apps) are unsupported on my iPad. Is there a way, through jailbreak or otherwise, to use my iPad as a touchscreen extension for my MacBook, or at least download Google Jamboard? The iPad is otherwise completely unused and SideCar unfortunately is not supported for such an old iPad.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Have you searched the App Store for ``remote touchpad``? There are dozens of apps allowing the use of iPads and iPhones as control devices, including touchpad, keyboard, and drawing tablet. I've tried a few at some point and they weren't bad, although far away from equivalence with a *real* touchpad. Unfortunately, I can't tell if they are compatible. (I know you said they are all incompatible, but I am almost certain you will need some software to do this, so I'm taking the shot that you've missed them)